# Recurrence sequence $a(n+1)=a(n)^3-a(n)+1$ and $a(1)=2$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

During the course of my research, I have stumbled on the sequence [A144787](http://oeis.org/A144787), which deals with the following recurrence:
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}^3-a_{n}+1$$
where $a_1=2$.

On the OEIS page there is a comment that says:

*For constant $c=1.240554576397679299452\ldots$*

However, there are no references to what this $c$ corresponds to, or what other formula it relates to. My intuition is that it has something to do with a double exponential function of some kind, such as $c^{3^n}$, but there are no links to any related articles or published papers that I could read.

Could someone please explain what the $c$ in this context means, and how it relates to the recurrence relation above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the constant $c$ such that $a_n = \lceil c^{3^n} \rceil$ forall $n\ge 1$.

$\log c$ is also the limit of the decreasing sequence $3^{-n} \log a_n$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That clears up the mystery. But do you know why these two formulae are linked? Are there any reference papers that I can read?

Comment: Any sequence of integers satisying $(a_n-1)^3 < a_{n+1}-1 < a_{n+1} < a_n^3$ is of the form $a_n = \lceil {c^{3^n}} \rceil$ where $c$ satisfies the aforementioned limit, and as far as anyone knows it is exactly as hard to compute $c$ with good precision than to compute the corresponding terms in the sequence. It brings absolutely nothing and there is nothing deep to this.

Comment: OK thanks. I just thought there was an academic reference somewhere but actually this looks quite trivial.